# error: src refsoec master: does not match any

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

i'm new here and need some help please. I'm making a course of Git and GitHub on Platzi, and when i want to push the origin to the repo, my terminal give me this error, anybody knows what does this means?

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI9aL.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master%3A+does+not+match+any

Comment: Check that you have commits to push. Check that the branch to push is named "master". If it's named "main" push "main" instead of "master".